# Hello everyone! I´am wondering why this bizarre error in the psql terminal

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

**This model allow me to insert new users using Postman**

```js
    sequelize.define('users', {
            id: {
              type: S.INTEGER,
              allowNull: false,
              autoIncrement: true,
              primaryKey: true
            },
            name: {
              type: S.STRING,
              allowNull: false,
              validate: {
                notNull: {
                  msg: 'Name is mandatory'
                },
                len: {
                  args: [2, 30],
                  msg: 'Name field must to be at least 2 characters long.'
                },
                isAlpha: true
              }
            },
            lastName: {
              type: S.STRING,
              allowNull: false,
              validate: {
                notNull: {
                  msg: 'Lastname is mandatory.'
                },
                len: {
                  args: [2, 50],
                  msg: 'Lastname field must to be at least 2 characters long.'
                },
                isAlpha: true,
              },
            }
          })
        }
```

**This is the express route i design**
*Another weird thing is that the `.findOrCreate` function doesn't work neither!*
I saw myself forced to divide the system in `.findOne` and `.create` functions.

```js
    server.post('/', async (req, res)=>{
      try {
        const { name, lastName } = req.body;
        if(!name || !lastName){
          res.send('All fields must to be completed')
        }
        const user = await Users.findOne({
          where: {
            email: email
          }
        })
        if(user){
          return res.send('This user already exists, choose a different one!').status(100);
        }
        const createUser = await Users.create({
            name: name,
            lastName: lastName
        })
        return res.send(createUser)
      } 
      catch (err) {
        res.send({ data: err }).status(400);
      }
    })
```

**The situation is that postman works properly but psql terminal throws the following error when i try to insert data to the model:**

```
        insert into users (name, lastName)
        values('John', 'Doe', 'jdoe@gmail.com', '12345678', 'wherever');
    
    ERROR:  no existe la columna «lastname» en la relación «users»
    LÍNEA 1: insert into users (name, lastName)
```

Comment: Sounds like your database table doesn't have a `lastname` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to make your life hard with upper case letters in your identifiers, you have to surround them with double quotes whenever you use them in SQL:

```
"lastName"
```

Comment: Thanks, it's easier to make my life simple with no uppercases. 